# QTableWidget with QPushbutton inside: resize problem

Tags: qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I'm an absolute beginner of Qt. I have the following MWE.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget table;

    table.setRowCount(2);
    table.setColumnCount(3);
    
    QPushButton button("Push me");

    table.setCellWidget(1, 1, &button);
    
    table.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I notice that when I resize the column of the table holding the mousebutton down the PushButton remain of the same dimension and it adjust to the correct size only when the mousebutton is released. Is this a wanted feature? How can I avoid it?

## EDIT

My setups are

1. Qt 5.15.0 on Linux
2. Qt 5.15.0 via PySide2 on Linux
3. Qt 5.15.0 on Windows

[image]

Comment: Which OS is that? On Windows 10 your code works as expected, i.e. the cell and the button are resized simultaneously.

Comment: My os is Linux.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug?

Comment: It seems so. Please report it and post a link here for future reference.

Comment: Btw, I tried the code on windows 10 and I have exactly the same problem. @scopchanov: which version of Windows do you use?

Comment: Qt5.14.1, Win10 v1909, MSVC2017

Comment: See the edits for my setup.

Comment: I've just tested it with Qt 5.15.0 and it behaves exactly as you describe. In 5.14.1 it works as expected. I suggest once again to report it as a Qt 5.15.0 specific bug.